# How to fill empty (gap) column with special condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `products` with the following columns:

- productID: numbers from 1 to 800
- name: the product name
- description: more info about products

The view of table :

```
productID | name    | description
----------+---------+---------------
      145 | name145 | description145
      146 | name146 | "empty col"
      147 | name147 | description147
      148 | name148 | "empty col" 
      149 | name149 | "empty col" 
      150 | name150 | "empty col" 
      151 | name151 | "empty col"
      152 | name152 | description152
```

Now I want to know how I can put an instant value some "x-name-description" on this empty col and fill them when this empty gap aren't continuous?

Comment: are you wanting to display some default value in the query results? or do you want a default value in the table?

Answer (score 2):

It's happened to me some similar situation. What I did, was

```
IFNULL(NULLIF(X, '' ), 0)
```

Attribute X is assumed to be empty if it is an empty String, so after that you can declare as a zero instead of last value. In another case, it would remain its original value.

Anyway, hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

If do you want the query to return a default value for field `description` if it is null, try a query like

```
SELECT productID, name, IFNULL(description, "some value") 
from products WHERE...
```

If you want to update the table, just use

```
UPDATE products set description = 'some value' WHERE description IS NULL
```

This work if the `description` field of the record is NULL.

Comment: Tnx ,Your mean of NULL is to set "NULL" in col?

Comment: the codes don't work, I think because the cols are empty and not null. can we do some work to set NULL value each col that it is empty?

Comment: @Hadi: What is *empty*? Equal to `''`?

Comment: @Hadi if the column is equal to `''` try to run the update query using `WHERE description = ''`

Comment: @Gianluca : no , my mean of empty is empty,please see this image from table: http://up.iranblog.com/images/50823977361612900411.jpg

Comment: Try to execute the query `select count(*) from products where length(description) = 0`. If this query return a value greater than 0, then you should can write something like `SELECT productID, name, IF(LENGTH(description) > 0, description, "some value") WHERE....` which return the field `description` if it has a length > 0 or return "some value" otherwhile. This shild work even if some value of `description` is NULL

Comment: @Gianluca : select count(*) from products where length(description) = 0 work OK and return true value but now what must I add after WHERE....??? in SELECT productID, name, IF(LENGTH(description) > 0, description, "some value") WHERE....

Comment: The WHERE part depend on what you want to do. My query was just an example, I suppose that you want to select a specified item, so a possible WHERE part can be `... WHERE productID = <product_id_code>` or you can select it by name or you can just use `IF(LENGTH(description) > 0, description, "some value")` in every query where you select the description field

Comment: @Gianluca : tnx man but how to fill this empty field now? all of this query are for select but my purpose is fill them!

Comment: Use something like `update products set description = 'some value' where LENGTH(description) = 0`